# nginx serve request to a json api service via sockets configuration

Tags: ruby, json, sockets, nginx, puma

my grape app runs on localhost like so:
bundle exec rackup -p 9292

and after that when going to `http://localhost:9292/api/v1/ping`,

you get a json response `{"res":"pong"}`

now,i'm trying to set it up in production. so I decided to run it on puma and nginx config. 
installed puma and ran it on a socket.

```
⇒  bundle exec puma -b unix:///tmp/my_app.sock
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 2.10.2 (ruby 2.1.2-p95), codename: Robots on Comets
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
* Environment: development
env :: development
Service started, go to town.
* Listening on unix:///tmp/my_app.sock
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

set up nginx with a config like this:

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;


    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;

    upstream my_app {
        server unix:///tmp/my_app.sock;

   }
    server {
        listen       8989;
        server_name  my_app;


    root /Volumes/dev/my_app;

    access_log  /Volumes/dev/my_app/service/log/host.access.log;
    error_log  /Volumes/dev/my_app/service/log/error.access.log;

    location / {
       root              /Volumes/dev/my_app/;
       gzip_static       on;
       expires           max;
       add_header        Cache-Control public;
   }

}
```

and I expect it to act the same. I browsed to 
`http://localhost:8989/api/v1/ping`
but got `404 Not Found` from nginx .

The error log showed :

`2015/01/07 21:51:15 [error] 62300#0: *2 open() "/Volumes/dev/my_app/api/v1/ping" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: my_app, request: "GET /api/v1/ping HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8989"`

maybe it's thinking it's service static content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your code, nginx serves first the static contents of `root` instead of the `upstream my_app`. Use the `root` to serve only the static files and the `upstream` to route request to the app server. This reduced nginx config might help you:

```
upstream my_app {
  server unix:/tmp/my_app.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  ...

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://my_app;
  }
}
```